# How to measure the amount of data copied in NVIDIA nsight systems?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight

**Trivia**

In NVIDIA Nsight Systems you can use the `--stats=true` flag to get the details for data transfer between GPU and CPU. The output includes a section similar to what follows:

```sh
CUDA Memory Operation Statistics (KiB)

              Total      Operations              Average            Minimum              Maximum  Name                                                                            
-------------------  --------------  -------------------  -----------------  -------------------  -------------------
           8192.000               2             4096.000           4096.000             4096.000  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]                                                              
         528384.000               2           264192.000           4096.000           524288.000  [CUDA memcpy DtoD]
```

**Question**

Is it possible to get this statistics per API call? That is, can we get the amount of data transferred between Host/Device in each of the `cudaMemCpyxxx` calls?

Comment: You can get this information from the timeline view in the GUI, but I assume that is not what you are asking.

Comment: To do it from the command line, [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/transitioning-nsight-systems-nvidia-visual-profiler-nvprof/) has the steps in "Extending the Summary Statistics"  1. export to sqlite database  2. build appropriate database query  3. profit

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella. That works for me. But the GUI doesn't show that information. Can you please elaborate a bit? (I can get that information for kernels but not `cudaMemcpyxxx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this purely from the CLI, I suggest following the guidance given in [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/transitioning-nsight-systems-nvidia-visual-profiler-nvprof/) starting at "Extending the Summary Statistics".  The basic steps are to export the profile data as a sqlite database, then formulate a database query to extract the data that you want.  I acknowledge this is not a compelete recipe.

If using the GUI is acceptable, I think it is pretty straightforward.  Suppose we had a very simple CUDA program:

```
int main(){

        int *d1, *d2;
        int *h1, *h2;
        h1 = new int[8192];
        h2 = new int[262144];
        cudaMalloc(&d1, 32768);
        cudaMalloc(&d2, 1048576);
        cudaMemcpy(d1, h1, 32768, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d2, h2, 1048576, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

These are the steps:

1. You could either do interactive profiling directly from the GUI as covered [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/transitioning-nsight-systems-nvidia-visual-profiler-nvprof/)  or you could start with the CLI.  To start with the CLI, run a command like this:

   ```
   nsys profile --trace=cuda ./my_app
   ```

   among other activities, this will create a report file of the name `reportX.qdrep` where `X` is really a number like 1, or 2, or 3, etc.
2. Open up the GUI, and File...Open the above `reportX.qdrep` file.  In this case, the GUI need not be on the same machine, but it should be of a version greater than or equal to the CLI version used to create the report file.
3. *Fully expand all the rows* in the timeline pertaining to the CUDA activities.
4. Hover your mouse over the desired operation of interest:

[image]